# Reduction of Order On Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, frobenius-method, reduction-of-order-ode

> Suppose $y_1 (x)$ is a solution to $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$.  Use
> reduction of order to show that a second solution is $y_2 (x) = y_1
> (x) \int \frac{e^{-\int p(x)dx}}{(y_1 (x))^2} dx$.

I plugged the guess $v(x)y_1 (x)$ into the ODE and obtained $v''y_1 + 2v'y_1' + pv'y_1 = 0$.

The substitution $w(x) = v'$ yields the first-order ODE $w' = -\frac{2y_1' + py_1}{y_1}w$, but this is hard to solve because $w$, $y_1$ and $p$ are all functions of $x$.  Additionally, this exercise appears in the section on The Method of Frobenius, so I may be doing something different than the intended approach.

Is this work correct, and if so, how can I obtain the stated result from this point?

Comment: It's separable. $\dfrac {v''}{v'}=(\ln v')'$

Comment: It's separable, but I'm not sure how to deal with the multiple functions of $x$.

Comment: You try to deduce a general formula for $y_2$  so you dont need to calculate the integral to get an explicit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y_2=vy_1$$
$$y'_2=v'y_1+vy_1'$$
$$y''_2=v''y_1+2v'y'_1+vy''_1$$
So that:
$$y''_2 + p(x)y'_2 + q(x)y_2 = 0$$
Becomes:
$$ v''y_1+2v'y'_1+vy''_1+ p(x)(v'y_1+vy_1') + q(x)vy_1 = 0$$
$$ v''y_1+2v'y'_1+ p(x)v'y_1  = 0$$

$$ v''y_1+v'(2y'_1+ p(x)y_1)  = 0$$
This is separable.
$$ (\ln v')'=-\dfrac {2y'_1+ p(x)y_1 }{y_1}$$
$$ \ln v'=-\int \dfrac {2y'_1+ p(x) y_1}{y_1}dx$$
$$ \ln v'=-2 \ln (y_1)-\int  { p(x) }dx$$
$$ v'=\dfrac {e^{-\int  { p(x) }dx}}{ y_1^2}$$
$$ v=\int \dfrac {e^{-\int { p(x) }dx}}{ y_1^2}dx$$
Finally:
$$ y_2= {y_1}\int \dfrac {e^{-\int { p(x) }dx}}{ y_1^2}dx$$